# Cypher - Collecting relationships across different match clauses

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to collect relationships from different match clauses as a single column in the results. To be more specific, I have created an example that corresponds to my use case and can be found here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/3g84gc. r1, r2 and r3 are relationships from different match clauses. There is only one valuation of target where multiple relationships are returned:

```
target = (0:Crew {name:"Neo"}), 
r1 = (0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1), 
r2 = (0)-[1:LOVES]->(2), 
r3 = (1)-[2:KNOWS]->(2).
```

What I want is:

```
target = (0:Crew {name:"Neo"}), 
rels = (0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1), (0)-[1:LOVES]->(2), (1)-[2:KNOWS]->(2)
```

I would like to do this WITHOUT having to specify all relationships in the return clause and then manually parse relationship columns. It would also be favourable to order valuations of target by the number of relationships found.

Is there a way to do this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, I think the following `RETURN` would give you what you want:

```
RETURN DISTINCT target, [r1,r2,r3]
```

In the console example that you shared, this returns `null` values for the second and third positions of the array, but you can fix that, if you want, by changing the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses to `MATCH`

Comment: That is handy in grouping relationships and is certainly a partial answer to my question. However, ideally I wouldn't want to have to specify all the relationships within [ ] . Getting a bit abstract about this problem, it occurs to me that any solution to my question would have to involve a higher order cypher query language that can express a variable for relationship variables. Otherwise, it would not be possible to express that I want to return all valuations of relationship variables that themselves are valuations of the higher order relationship variable.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but I have something of a stab in the dark at another possibility: `MATCH path = (target)-[0:KNOWS]->(b)-[2:KNOWS]->(c)<-[:LOVES]-(target) RETURN target, rels(path)`

Comment: That would work if I could put all the required relationships into a single match clause, but I cannot do that. If I created a path like this in each match clause I would still have the same/similar problem of collecting all paths across match statements first.

Comment: What about `RETURN rels(path1) + rels(path2)` etc...?

Comment: I think I will stick to the following: `MATCH (target)-[r1:KNOWS]-(m)
OPTIONAL MATCH (target)-[r2:LOVES]->(o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (o)-[r3:KNOWS]-(z)
WITH target,[r1,r2,r3] AS rels
RETURN DISTINCT target, rels, length(FILTER(x IN rels 
                                            WHERE x IS NOT NULL )) AS numRels
ORDER BY numRels DESC `